# Start process as system user

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, administrator

I was trying to read some values from some registry keys with code (c#) on windows and I found out that the reason why I was not able to read the values was because the admin user did not had permissions:

So I manually navegated to the registry key that was giving me trouble and this is how the permissions tab looked like:

[image]

So that made me thought about how can I run a process as the user "system"? That sounds weird but apparently there is a system user right? I know how to run as administrator but maybe it is also possible to run as system.

### Edit

here is my code. Basically I will like to traverse through all the registry keys:

```
class Program
{
    // class to store reg key.
    [Serializable]
    [DebuggerDisplay("Name = {Name}, Val = {value}, type={type}")]
    class MyRegKey
    {
        public string Name;
        public object value;
        public RegistryValueKind type;
        public List<MyRegKey> SubKeys = new List<MyRegKey>();
        public List<MyRegKey> Values = new List<MyRegKey>();
    }

    static MyRegKey root = new MyRegKey();

    static void TraverseTree(RegistryKey key, MyRegKey temp)
    {
        foreach (var v in key.GetValueNames())
        {            
            var kind = key.GetValueKind(v);
            var value = key.GetValue(v, null);
            var name = v;

            temp.Values.Add(new MyRegKey { Name = name, value = value, type = kind });
        }

        var x = key.GetSubKeyNames();
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            RegistryKey productKey;
            productKey = key.OpenSubKey(x[i], false); // <--------- Code crashes here

            if (productKey != null)
            {
                var y = new MyRegKey() { Name = productKey.Name };
                temp.SubKeys.Add(y);
                Foo(productKey, y);
            }
        }        
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        var key = Registry.LocalMachine;

        root.Name = key.Name;
        TraverseTree(key, root);
    }
}
```

I am running that code as an administrator...

And here is an image of how my program crashes stating that I don't have permissions:
[image]

Comment: I may be wrong here, but as far as I'm aware the only way to spawn a system process is either run a windows service under system account, or start a process from such a service.

Comment: There should be no issue reading the registry as a admin user, Can you show the code where you are fetching the registry keys, are you using the `Registry` class?

Comment: I will post my code soon... yeah I am using the Registry class

Comment: Are you right clicking on visual studio and selecting run as administrator? Running from an account that has admin access is not enough admin elevation must occur.

Comment: [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) -i -d -s c:\YouApp.exe or you need to know how write code which will act as system account

Comment: Another (but more complicated) option is to use backup/restore privilege to bypass the security.  I'm not sure offhand how that works on registry keys, you mightn't have to do anything but enable the privileges.

Answer (score 2):

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) `-s` run remote process in the System account

```
C:\Windows\system32>psexec -i -d -s cmd

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


cmd started on SERGMATCOMP with process ID 5356.
```

Output from the cmd with PID5356

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>whoami
nt authority\system
```